# Disable elements in dropdown after or before an index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

Hi i have two requirements to disable all the elements in drop down after and before selected index.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test option:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tests" id="test">
  <option value="1846">test</option>
  <option value="1962">test2</option>
  <option value="1846">test3</option>
  <option value="1962">test4</option>
  <option value="1846" selected>test5</option>
  <option value="1962">test6</option>
  <option value="1846">test7</option>
  <option value="1962">test8</option>
  <option value="1846">test9</option>
  <option value="1962">test10</option>
  <option value="1846">test11</option>
  <option value="1962">test12</option>
</select>
```

As of I'm able to disable all elements which are not selected but not sure how to put a filter based on selected index.

Comment: Which index do you need to be selected? If you disable all other `<option>` elements how are your users supposed to correct an accidental/wrong selection? At the very least this UI would need an undo/deselect/enable-all feature.

Comment: any index can be selected but i want to disable all elements after selected index.

Comment: May I just point out the inconsistency in your question: "*i have two requirements to disable all the elements in drop down after and before selected index.*" and in your comment: "*any index can be selected but i want to disable all elements after selected index*"?

Comment: This seems like a very poor user experience that's going to cause unnecessary frustration. Why would you want to disable those options in the first place? Does the user ever have a way to "unlock" them?

Comment: @david yes if i can get one of them working i can implement both.

Comment: @brightmatrix yes its a poor user experience but we need to show it user , and its customer's requirement. Any ideas are most welcome may be if i can convince them.

Comment: @quorious Sure, I can help think up other options. What is the user doing when they interact with this menu? Why would some options be disabled and not others? This seems like it would be a good use case for two menus: when the user makes a choice in the first, it either alters the second or makes a hidden second menu (with additional options) visible.

Comment: suppose they want to upgrade a plan the all they can select is higher value than the current one and if they want to downgrade they can only go lower than the current one.
Will it be a good idea to remove irrelevant entries from page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

---

```
$('#test option').each(function(index,value) {
    if(index > 2) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: i can't rely on values they may not be in order. Need to do with index only.

Comment: thanks alot mate it worked 
i used : if(index > $("#test option:selected").index())

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $('#test option:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', "disabled");
    $('#test option[selected]').attr('disabled', false);
  });

  $("#resetData").click(function() {
    $('#test option[disabled=disabled]').attr('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tests" id="test">
  <option value="1846">test</option>
  <option value="1962">test2</option>
  <option value="1846">test3</option>
  <option value="1962">test4</option>
  <option value="1846">test5</option>
  <option value="1962">test6</option>
  <option value="1846">test7</option>
  <option value="1962">test8</option>
  <option value="1846">test9</option>
  <option value="1962">test10</option>
  <option value="1846">test11</option>
  <option value="1962">test12</option>
</select>
<button id="resetData">Enable All</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the general sibling selector to select the ones after

```
$('#test option:selected ~ option')
```

To select the options before the selected option you might have to use something like

```
$('#test option:selected').prevAll()
```

Comment: The tilde (`~`) is the  `general sibling` combinator, the `adjacent-sibling` combinator is the `+` character.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // bind the anonymous function of the on() method
  // as the event-handler for the change event:
  $('#test').on('change', function () {

    // retrieving the newly-selected <option> element's
    // selectedIndex property:
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;

    // converting the HTMLOptionsCollection (the <option>
    // children of the <select> element) into a jQuery
    // collection and using the filter() method:        
    $(this.options).filter(function(i){

      // returning any option whose index is not equal to
      // the selectedIndex:
      return i != selectedIndex;

    // using the prop() method to set the disabled property
    // of the retained elements to true:
    }).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Note that, in the above, you could pass a specific index to the function instead of using the `this.selectedIndex` property of the `<select>` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('change', function () {
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    
    $(this.options).filter(function(i){
      return i != selectedIndex;
    }).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tests" id="test">
  <option value="1846">test</option>
  <option value="1962">test2</option>
  <option value="1846">test3</option>
  <option value="1962">test4</option>
  <option value="1846" selected>test5</option>
  <option value="1962">test6</option>
  <option value="1846">test7</option>
  <option value="1962">test8</option>
  <option value="1846">test9</option>
  <option value="1962">test10</option>
  <option value="1846">test11</option>
  <option value="1962">test12</option>
</select>
<button id="resetData">Reset</button>
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('change', function() {

    // again: storing the index of the element:
    var selected = this.selectedIndex;

    // using the prop() method's anonymous function,
    // passing in the i argument (the index of the
    // current <option> in the collection:
    $(this.options).prop('disabled', function(i) {

      // if i is equal to the selected index we return
      // false (not-true), otherwise we return true
      // (not-false) to set the disabled property of
      // the current <option>:
      return !( i === selected);
    });
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
    
    var selected = this.selectedIndex;
    
    $(this.options).prop('disabled', function(i) {
      return !( i === selected);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tests" id="test">
  <option value="1846">test</option>
  <option value="1962">test2</option>
  <option value="1846">test3</option>
  <option value="1962">test4</option>
  <option value="1846" selected>test5</option>
  <option value="1962">test6</option>
  <option value="1846">test7</option>
  <option value="1962">test8</option>
  <option value="1846">test9</option>
  <option value="1962">test10</option>
  <option value="1846">test11</option>
  <option value="1962">test12</option>
</select>
<button id="resetData">Reset</button>
```

Or, a little more concisely - albeit not using the `index` property in this iteration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('change', function () {

    // using only the prop() method and its anonymous function:
    $(this.options).prop('disabled', function(){
      // this sets the disabled property of each element
      // according to the inverse of its selected property,
      // if the element is selected we return false, if
      // it's not selected we return true:
      return !this.selected;
    });
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
    $(this.options).prop('disabled', function() {
      return !this.selected;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tests" id="test">
  <option value="1846">test</option>
  <option value="1962">test2</option>
  <option value="1846">test3</option>
  <option value="1962">test4</option>
  <option value="1846" selected>test5</option>
  <option value="1962">test6</option>
  <option value="1846">test7</option>
  <option value="1962">test8</option>
  <option value="1846">test9</option>
  <option value="1962">test10</option>
  <option value="1846">test11</option>
  <option value="1962">test12</option>
</select>
<button id="resetData">Reset</button>
```

All of the above approaches will disable all `<option>` elements other than the selected `<option>`, as per the first line in your question; however as that seems to be not what you want I'll offer you the final alternative:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
    // retrieving all the <options>:
    $(this.options)
      // finding the <option> at the same index as the
      // selected index:
      .eq(this.selectedIndex)
      // retrieving all the subsequent sibling elements:
      .nextAll()
      // updating their 'disabled' property to true:
      .prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
    $(this.options).eq(this.selectedIndex).nextAll().prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tests" id="test">
  <option value="1846">test</option>
  <option value="1962">test2</option>
  <option value="1846">test3</option>
  <option value="1962">test4</option>
  <option value="1846" selected>test5</option>
  <option value="1962">test6</option>
  <option value="1846">test7</option>
  <option value="1962">test8</option>
  <option value="1846">test9</option>
  <option value="1962">test10</option>
  <option value="1846">test11</option>
  <option value="1962">test12</option>
</select>
<button id="resetData">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $('#test option').not(':selected').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```